# lsusb doesn't list my android device

Tags: usb, android, mtp, lsusb

Three days I'm striggling with this problem. `lsusb` isn't detecting my ASUS Fonepad 7, but detects my Lumia, which is a Windows Phone device. I tried plugging my sister's phone, my dad's phone, which are both android marshmallow devices, but no android is ever detected. Every solution I find in the Internet is based on the `51-android.rules` file or enabling MTP on the device itself. This, however is still not working on my machine. I have the `.rules` file and MTP is enabled on my ASUS Fonepad 7. Yet, when I run `lsusb`, no android device is detected, which also affects `adb devices`'s results. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** I'm using ElementaryOS Freya, based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue with

> Android Smartphone: Huawei Honor 7S; OS: Android 8.1.0;
> Debugging: usb-debugging activated; Networking: MTP activated)

on:

> Linux fedora 6.7.10-100.fc38.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Mar 18 18:51:12 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and like you many Forum sites wrote about missing udev-rules. The smartphone could not be identified with:

```
sudo adb devices
```

First you could try to check hardware components, like:

- try different usb-ports on laptop
- clean usb-connector of fonetab, mobile, laptop (eg. with air-pressure can, cotton-bud, ...)
- check correct cable-type (data cables tend to be bigger than thin
  charge-only cables)

Otherwise try to post *more information* by posting a log of your system, like:

```
sudo apt-get install lshw
```

then save it into a sysinfo file like:

```
sudo lshw -html > sysinfo.txt
```

and post it here like:

> Linux fedora 6.7.10-100.fc38.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Mar 18 18:51:12 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

In my case, I used a **charging cable instead of a data-transfer cable**, and there is very useful background information about the differences [here](https://www.dignited.com/50330/usb-data-cable-vs-usb-charging-cable/). After sorting that out, I followed the information from other Forums for Fedora OS.

Identify hardware-device:

```
lsusb
```

which returns:

> Bus 001 Device 019: ID 12d1:107f Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. DUA-L22

Then, check for the Android plugdev-group:

```
cat /etc/groups
```

if not there, then:

```
sudo groupadd plugdev
sudo usermod -aG plugdev $LOGNAME
```

Now adding the missing udev-rules:

```
cd /etc/udev/
vim 51-android-rules
```

and add the line from the lsusb ID-output:

> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="107f", MODE="0666"

Finally restart the adb-server:

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

Now check if the device is listed:

```
adb devices
```

which returns the device if it's found:

> MNV9K187064XX482  devices

and can be accessed with abd shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting USB debugging to enabled in the developer options. You should be able to run lsusb then.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem - the cable didn't support data transfer. Try changing the cable that you use to connect the device to.